# $\triangle ABC$ is a triangle with internal point $O$. Find $\angle x$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

As title states, the triangle in the following figure has 3 equal sides and some given angles, and the goal is to find the measure of $\angle x$. As always, I'll post my own approach here, please share your own approaches as well!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple approach, based on your picture, using the law of sines:

$$\angle CAO=40-x,\angle COA=140^{\circ} \implies \frac{\sin (40-x)^{\circ}}{\sin 140^{\circ}}=\frac {\sin (20+x)^{\circ}}{\sin 40^{\circ}}=\frac{\sin (20+x)^{\circ}}{\sin 140^{\circ}}$$

$$\implies \sin (40-x)^{\circ}=\sin (20+x)^{\circ}\implies 40-x=20+x\implies x=10^{\circ}.$$

Comment: Logically $\sin (40-x)^{\circ}=\sin (20+x)^{\circ}\implies 40-x=20+x$ $\color{red}{or}$ implies $40-x=180 - (20+x)$ (even if this second solution doesn't work)

Comment: Really smart trig approach

Answer (score 1):

This'll be my approach. I'll add an explanation below!

[image]

Here's how I go about it:

1.) Label the triangle $\triangle ABC$ with the internal point $O$. Rotate $\triangle BOC$ by $180°$ about the line segment $BC$ such that a new triangle $\triangle BDC$ is formed that is congruent to $\triangle BOC$. Connect $A$ with $D$ via $AD$.

2.) Notice that $\angle ABD=60$ and $AB=BD=BO$, this means that $\triangle ABD$ is equilateral, therefore $AB=BO=BD=AD=CD$. This proves that point $D$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$. Therefore $\angle ACB$ is half of $\angle ADB$. Which means that $x+20=30$, therefore, $x=10$.